# How to set up the Magento (1.8.1) cron job in Cpanel

Tags: php, magento, cron, magento-1.8

I want to know how to run Cron job in magento and for the same i Google and i got more than one solution but i was little bit confusion which will be useful to me.

I want to run the cron job bcoz i want to use Abandon cart extension plz check this installation link:
http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/abandoned-carts/configuration/general

I have cPanel access but dont know which command to use to run cron job.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Hey guys what happen nobody knows the solution for the above one.

Answer (score -1):

You can google of how to setup a cron in cpanel. There are a lot of articles.
After that you need to setup cron in your magento admin side.
And thats it. 
If you need to change time for cron job of abandoned cart extension you can do it to change cron_job section in config.xml file of abandoned cart extension.